# Switching TabBar produces error

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: storyboard]

To switch from A to B I am using the following code:

```
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Then when hitting the TabBar to go back to C, my app crashes with no error in console but this show in the AppDelegate:

[image: error]

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception breakpoint on All Exceptions and you should see why it is crashing.

[image]

Out of curiosity, why are you doing a `popToRootViewController` when changing tabs?